app.name variable is null after upgrading to Mule Runtime 4.6.0
When we upgraded to Mule Runtime 4.6.0, we started seeing errors in our logs that the app.name is null.
But it expects one of these combinations:
  (Array, Array)
  (Date, Time)
  (Date, LocalTime)
  (Date, TimeZone)
  (LocalDateTime, TimeZone)
  (LocalTime, Date)
  (LocalTime, TimeZone)
  (Object, Object)
  (String, String)
  (Time, Date)
  (TimeZone, LocalDateTime)
  (TimeZone, Date)
  (TimeZone, LocalTime)

1| 'Entry of: ' ++ (app.name match(/message-logging-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-(.*)-main/))[1] ++ attributes.requestUri
                ^^
Trace:
  at ++ (line: 1, column: 14)
  at main (line: 1, column: 80)"" evaluating expression: ""'Entry of: ' ++ (app.name match(/message-logging-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-(.*)-main/))[1] ++ attributes.requestUri"".

I tried checking the value of app but it also does not return any value. Is there any updates need on the RTF side to get value after upgrading?

[edit] the question to add the complete error message with all lines and using [code block] format. Also add the line that caused the error as XML with [code block] format too. Don't use inline cose format. Please read [ask] for more details.
